# Setup with BIOS but GPT partition table (due to 3 TB disk)?

Tags: 12.04, server, grub2, setup

How can I use a disk with GPT partition table on a system with a BIOS but no (U)EFI?

I have a system with a 3 TB drive (no other drives and since this is *a remote machine* I have no choices here) and with a GPT for obvious reasons. Ubuntu 12.04 is being bootstrapped onto the system and this worked so far. Now after bind-mounting `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` from the host into the target system and `chroot`ing into it, I installed `linux-image-server` which worked fine (after linking `/sbin/initctl` as `/bin/true`). Because this is a remote machine I have to do all of this via SSH and have no bootable CD or anything. I can boot into a rescue system if it fails, though (PXE).

Now I know that `grub2` is supposed to support the scenario, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to install it.

The boot (and root) device is to be `/dev/md0`, composed of `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` in RAID mode 0. With `/dev/md0` mounted under `/target` I am running:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/target --no-floppy /dev/sda
```

which fails with:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: This GPT partition label has no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible!.
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required when the root device is on a RAID array or LVM volume.
```

So how can I get `grub2` installed in order to have this BIOS-based system boot properly?

**Note:** it doesn't matter whether I run this inside or outside the `chroot` environment. The error and output are identical. Likely because I bind-mounted `/dev` etc into place. Of course appropriate adjustments to the command line (no `--root-directory=`) have been made.

Comment: First you said one drive, then you said raid array.  Which is it?

Comment: @psusi: it's two physical disks, but the idea is to use software RAID 1, as can be seen from the question. Apologies for the confusion, though.

Comment: Where exactly is the bios_grub partition created? First partition of /dev/md0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a bios_grub partition on the disk.  You can do this with `parted` and setting the bios_grub flag on the partition.  1 MiB is sufficient, but it needs to be in the lower 2TiB of the disk.