# Problem while Dual booting windows 8 pro with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a HP Pavilion-15-n004tx laptop. It supports UEFI. However when i installed Windows 8 on it, i disabled the UEFI and installed the Windows in **Legacy** BIOS mode. I wanted to dual boot it with Ubuntu 13.10. I read the Instructions from [this link.](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)

Now when i tried the live USB then in 'Try Ubuntu without installing' mode , i got the error saying that 'Your system is running in low graphics'. I tried Troubleshooting the problem after reading many questions from this site. They implied that i had to first install the Ubuntu and then open it in Recovery mode.

So when i tried Installing Ubuntu, everything worked fine and Ubuntu 13.10 was successfully installed on my system but when i rebooted the computer then i didn't get any GRUB menu and Windows 8 started automatically. So i made live USB of **BOOT-REPAIR** and ran it. But it didn't solve the problem as instead of GRUB menu, Windows 8 started **automatically like before**. How can i get the GRUB menu to select between Windows and Ubuntu.

I am attaching the **boot-info summary** given by Boot-Repair. Additionally i am uploading the result of 'msinfo32' command in Windows. I am also uploading the Screen obtained while installation of Ubuntu at 'Something Else'.

I would be really obliged to anyone who can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

PS: I am unable to attach Photos so i am providing the links . Thanks!

The link for Boot Info Summary is : 
[Boot Info Log](http://m.uploadedit.com/b033/139817354978.txt)

Comment: post your boot-repair log link.

Comment: The link for msinfo32 is : http://oi57.tinypic.com/bveh0.jpg

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hi, I have posted the link above.

Comment: The link for 'Something Else' photo is : http://oi62.tinypic.com/suu644.jpg

Comment: did you select recommended repair option in boot-repair?

Comment: After boot-repair, did you able to boot into which os? Did you able to see grub on stratup?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes i selected the Recommended Repair option in boot-repair and after boot-repair i was able to boot automatically into Windows 8.There was no GRUB from which i could select the OS.

Comment: i think grub failed to install on `/dev/sda`, run this command on your Ubuntu live disk `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.After that reboot your system.

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/a/449821/202806 answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj As asked by you i tried the above command but an error message was produced saying-- ' Path '/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible.Aborting '

Answer (score 0):

Try to install grub on your `/` partition by running these commands on terminal(Ubuntu live disk),

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

It will install grub on your root `/dev/sda7` partition.

Comment: There was an error message : "/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup:warning: This LMD has no Embedding Partition;embedding won't be possible. Embedding is not possible.GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.However blocklists are unreliable and their use is discouraged. will not proceed with blocklists "

Comment: post that error message.

Comment: I have edited the above comment to include the error message. Thanks!

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/239252/setup-with-bios-but-gpt-partition-table-due-to-3-tb-disk and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1053793

Comment: I couldn't understand much there as i am currently a rookie. However will this problem be solved if i reinstalled the Windows 8 in UEFI environment and then tried to reinstall Ubuntu ? Also will all my data on other partitions be lost if i reinstall the windows in UEFI ?

Comment: no just only your c partition if you choose custom option during windows installation.

Comment: But will the problem be solved ?

Comment: i think, you need to format and reinstall Ubuntu only.

Comment: How should i do it differently than i have done until now?