# Any advantage to installing Ubuntu-only system with UEFI vs Legacy?

Tags: boot, uefi

I'm building a new Ubuntu/Mythbuntu system.  It's not dual-boot with Windows or any other OS.  New motherboard supports UEFI (of course).  Should I install it as UEFI or stick with Legacy?

I ask because I've been having some trouble trying to install as UEFI (depending on Ubuntu/Mythbuntu flavor used, it either fails during install or on first boot).  That will be another thread if it turns out UEFI is the "preferred" way to go.

Comment: Yes, it is basically a duplicate - go to the link above for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost no difference. Boot time on UEFI may be a bit less.

Besides UEFI has native support of GPT disks.

But it is possible to get bios support of a GPT partitioned disk by creating a special partition [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/239342/167850).

It is not worth the effort to force installing with UEFI if there are problems.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up making UEFI work with a different distribution, but good to know.